# How to manully trigger Media Access from a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

Yeah, I know if I just run `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` It will ask the user to Allow or Block. If the user accidentally clicks Block, Is it possible to ask the user again on any button click?

Comment: See [Privacy and security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#privacy_and_security). Specifically, a browser can ask every time or can implement a once-per-domain approach. So, call `.getUserMedia()` again, but there's no guarantee the browser will ask again and no way for the page to force the browser to ask again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to ```getUserMedia()``` method but it doesn't work. I have to manually remove Not allowed permission from settings.